# Removed MAMP from OS X, dyld still using MAMP libraries

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mamp, dylib

When I try and use a populator or sphinx on a Ruby app I keep receiving dyld errors. I used to use MAMP on OS X Leopard but since I've upgraded to Snow Leopard and am now using standalone MySQL (10.5 64-bit).

```
$ rake ts:index
```

Would return

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/indexer
  Reason: image not found
rake aborted!
```

Even though to remove MAMP I just deleted the /Applications/MAMP directory. But it still looks like dylib has references to it.

I've tried running:

```
$ sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -verify
```

and restarting but the problem still persists.

OS X 10.6.1, MySQL 5.0.85 (x86_64)

Comment: How did you build /usr/local/bin/indexer - I suspect that was built when you had MAMP installed

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.com/BouldrMatt fixed it.

Comment: How? It would be nice for him/you to share the solution with the rest of us. :)